# Did my answer address the problem that was asked?

Tags: discussion, answers

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620982/reading-csv-file-as-dictionary-using-pandas) earlier, at least I thought I did. From my understanding, the OP wanted to have the values of the dataframe (data without column names) part of a dictionary. He then edited the question with the expected output.

I posted my answer, but got quickly downvoted and questioned about my approach. I edited the answer to eliminate the confusion, but even that didn't seem enough.

The way that I approached the problem is by loading the data into a dataframe, then converting the values only to dict for which I showed the output.

So, did I not answer the question as it was described? I'm more than comfortable removing the answer if it doesn't address the issue at hand.

Comment: Read the comments on the answer to see why those that read it didn't feel like it was a good answer.  And you got *one downvote*.  You don't need to come to meta to ask for one downvote *that already has explanatory comments* to get explained.  Heck you even already had a pity upvote on your low quality answer already; what more could you ask for?

Comment: I'm not here to complain about the downvote. I'm honestly trying to find out if my answer did actually address the problem. If meta isn't the place for that, then what would be? I did read the comments, that's why I'm still a little confused.

Comment: Apparently the person who commented felt otherwise **and explained why**, so clearly you *already* have an explanation as to why someone feels your answer doesn't answer the question.  That said, "it is an answer" is a very low bar.  Regardless of whether or not what you posted is an answer, it's unquestionably not a *quality* answer.

Comment: Their explanation, to me, was them misunderstanding my code, hence why I'm here. Also, if you want to tell me that it my answer is low quality that's perfectly fine, but providing additional insight would help fix the problem for future posts.

Comment: If you feel that they misunderstood your answer then *explain it to them* and see if your edit resolved their concerns.  As for why your answer is low quality, it's a code only answer to a trivially searchable problem that will never help a single person that reads it (in no small part because nobody with that problem is likely to ever read it).

Answer (score 0):

For the question there is only **one answer, but Many of methods** to get that. Every one like shortcuts as usual. Bcz we always pickup easiest way to do something.

For an answer also its same. I read [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33621064/4595675) and [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33621073/4595675)'s answer. By compare both answer **Alexander's is pretty strait forward** about OP Question.

In your question [Zizouz212](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620982/reading-csv-file-as-dictionary-using-pandas#comment55016738_33621064) commented with the errors of your code.  OP needs to assing all the data to `dt` variable. So that's [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33621073/4595675) did that correctly how OP needs.

My opinion is read [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [The “best practice” answer etiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145909/the-best-practice-answer-etiquette)

Hopes this gives you idea

Comment: "**Bcz** we always pickup easiest way to do something." Har har har.

Comment: @Gimby ya of course. Bz humns are lazy felow in the world

Comment: Might want to be careful about how lazy you are on spelling "assign" as the current spelling in your answer could be misconstrued... ;)

Comment: @Leb did you check this